# Unit Testing Chained Method Addition to Ruby Object

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, metaprogramming

I'm in a situation where for our projects, there is a desire for 100% code coverage in our unit testing.

In order to support some dereference operations, I had to utilize the ability to chain dynamic method calls. So I ended up with this open class addition defined on one of my source files:

```
class Object
  def call_method_chain(method_chain, arg=nil)
    return self if method_chain.empty?
    method_chain.split('.').inject(self) { |o,m|
      if arg.nil?
        o.send(m.intern)
      else
        o.send(m.intern, arg)
      end
    }
  end
end
```

It works wonderfully. The problem is it's the only part of my application that isn't showing up as covered by unit tests, even though the area that calls the above method is covered.

I can't figure out how to cover the above with some unit tests.

I have no idea how much information is too much information here, but just to give an idea, here is the code that actually uses the above (in a file called data_setter.rb):

```
module Symbiont
  module DataSetter
    # @param data [Hash] the data to use
    def using(data)
      data.each do |key, value|
        use_data_with(key, value) if object_enabled_for(key)
      end
    end

    def use_data_with(key, value)
      element = self.send("#{key}")
      self.call_method_chain("#{key}.set", value) if element.class == Watir::TextField
      self.call_method_chain("#{key}.set") if element.class == Watir::Radio
      self.call_method_chain("#{key}.select", value) if element.class == Watir::Select

      return self.call_method_chain("#{key}.check") if element.class == Watir::CheckBox and value
      return self.call_method_chain("#{key}.uncheck") if element.class == Watir::CheckBox
    end

    private

   def object_enabled_for(key)
     web_element = self.send("#{key}")
     web_element.enabled? and web_element.visible?
   end
  end
end
```

You can see using() calls use_data_with() and it's that latter method that relies on the call_method_chain() that I defined on Object.

Further, I have a unit test that exercises the using() method, which looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Symbiont::DataSetter do
  include_context :page
  include_context :element

  it 'will set data in a text field' do
    expect(watir_element).to receive(:visible?).and_return(true)
    expect(watir_element).to receive(:enabled?).and_return(true)
    expect(watir_browser).to receive(:text_field).with({:id => 'text_field'}).exactly(2).times.and_return(watir_element)
    watir_definition.using(:text_field => 'works')
  end
end
```

That test shows my logic calling the using() method. That test passes. When looking at my code coverage, the coverage of data_setter.rb is 100%. Yet the coverage report also shows that my call_method_chain() method is never being executed.

This is one of those cases where I fear strict adherence to unit testing coverage is causing more trouble than it's worth since I know the above logic is working.

**EDIT (based on response from Neil):**

I'm using SimpleCov for the coverage.

Regarding the coverage report and object, taking this:

```
 1  class Object
 2    def call_method_chain(method_chain, arg=nil)
 3      return self if method_chain.empty?
 4      method_chain.split('.').inject(self) { |o,m| #o.send(m.intern, arg) }
 5        if arg.nil?
 6          o.send(m.intern)
 7        else
 8          o.send(m.intern, arg)
 9        end
10      }
11    end
12  end
```

The report says that lines 1 and 2 are covered. They show up as green. Starting from 3 down to 9, it's all red.

Regarding my spec_helper.rb file, this is what it looks like, at the top:

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'coveralls'

Coveralls.wear!

SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter[
  SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
  Coveralls::SimpleCov::Formatter
]

SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter '/spec'
  coverage_dir "#{SimpleCov.root}/spec/reports/coverage"
  minimum_coverage 90
  maximum_coverage_drop 5
end

require 'symbiont'
```

I have found that if I make a simple test like this:

```
it 'allows methods to be chained' do
  methods = 'testing'.call_method_chain("reverse.capitalize")
end
```

That covers up to line 6 of my Object insertion. That leaves line 8, which I can't quite get to work. I tried this:

```
methods = 'testing'.call_method_chain("reverse.capitalize.eql?", 'GNITSET')
```

To no avail, however. So I *can* actually get it down to only one line not being covered, assuming I just use those little point tests like that. I'm not sure if that's in the spirit of good unit testing.

Comment: Does your coverage report show `class Object` is covered? I cannot see anything from your code sample that suggests that `call_method_chain` is not being called - in which case your problem is not "adherence to unit testing coverage" but a technical problem with measuring the coverage. Could you show start of file (spec_helper.rb?) where coverage tool is invoked - are there any `requires` before it? Are you filtering the coverage report to remove Ruby built-ins or standard library? Which coverage tool are you using?

Comment: Edited the post to answer your questions.

Comment: With `'testing'.call_method_chain("reverse.capitalize.eql?", 'GNITSET')` I think you expose a bug, as your code will call `'testing'.reverse( 'GNITSET' )` resulting in `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Comment: Possibly so, Neil. To back that up, I did find a statement that does work: `methods = 'testing'.call_method_chain("start_with?", 't')`. That works fine, interestingly enough, but it's only calling one method, not chaining multiples. So it appears this unit testing was valuable after all!

Comment: On the other hand, though, this works fine: `expect('testing'.call_method_chain("reverse.capitalize")).to eq('Gnitset')`. There I am chaining multiples.

Comment: OK, I think I can see the problem now. Your code is buggy, and the coverage report is giving you false security: e.g. `self.call_method_chain("#{key}.select", value) if element.class == Watir::Select` is showing as covered because the `if` is being invoked, but you don't have tests that invoke the method (that you claim *must* be OK, so no need to write tests, surely :-). You *do* need to properly unit test your `call_method_chain` in isolation.

Comment: Also, if your company really does want 100% coverage to mean something, you need to break apart all the one-liner conditionals. `SimpleCov` cannot tell you properly how they have resolved/branched.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Yeah, that makes complete sense. This area of the logic has been very tough for me to test well, at least via unit tests. I'm learning though.

Comment: FWIW, I think Neil's comment about testing in isolation is REALLY important.  "Unit" == 1.  "Unit testing" == testing 1 thing at a time.  If you rely on other test cases to transitively cover the testing of methods like call_method_chain(), you're going to get yourself into trouble.  Make a dedicated test case for this.